# What do I need to make a small app running offline with a html/css ui?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Noob question here:

I wanna build a small app that's supposed to run offline on a desktop computer. It does not have much data to save, so i can either use a file or some form of a db, but here lies my question:

What language/tech can I use for handling and saving the data, that does not have to be connected to the internet?

I'm thankful for any tips!

Comment: You need to somehow store them locally. One way is to use browser side cache. You can make use of a service worker. its very simple.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/)

Answer (score 1):

Try out the electron: https://electronjs.org/
You can create cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS with electron.